# Usability of Cache

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, dictionary

In my Application I build a Cache in the form of **`HashMap`** by taking its **`key-value`** from Database. 
Now I have to add something in this cache, here what I am doing is update or insert this new value into the database and refresh Cache so it should populate by updated Database.
Now for that what I am doing is -
**1.**  I am taking two **`Maps`** , **`cache1`** and **`cache2`** so when one cache is in use other will be an empty cache
**2.** When I want to refresh cache I start populating the empty cache and when it is done I clear the earlier cache.
**3.** All data will be given by this new cache. 
*I just want to know if my approach is fine or I can do anything else which is more productive and efficient.* Because I feel I don't need two map for doing this but then I think if I use only one it can affect the data accuracy.

**EDIT :**
Here is something you need to know about the application before answer.
1. The Data is neither so huge nor very small.
2. It takes approx 2-3 mins to populate cache from Database.
3. Refreshes are not much frequent only once or twice in a day required.
4. Application runs 24 Hrs(One Restart of Server/Day in early morning)

Comment: Considering that you've said nothing about the actual requirements, the size of the data, the frequency of refreshes, the lifetime of the application, etc, etc, etc no one here is qualified to answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Something that you can try is EHCache, here you can find an example : [ehcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214105/hello-world-example-for-ehcache)

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to implement a simple cache you can use SoftReference. This is a much better way to implement cache than using HashMap.

As when you store a reference to HashMap it stores the Strong Reference to the object and when you set the object to `null`, it will still not be garbage collected as there is a strong reference to it in the map.

For more on caches here is a great link:
[Cache based on SoftReference](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/CachebasedonSoftReference.htm)

Comment: it is possible that ehcache may be using the same technique