# TokenStorage for Authentication in Java

Tags: java, authentication, token

I have a Map containing users that have been authenticated with my system. the key is the token that's being generated, the value is the actual user instance. Now I'd like to remove a user after a certain amount of inactivity. I am more than sure, there's a mechanism available for this (something like Googles LoadingCache but specially for this situation (login/tokenstorage) 
Could you suggest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/) for this purposes.

It's easy to use and it allows you to define various invalidation criteria for the tokens, such as `timeToIdleSeconds` and `timeToLiveSeconds`.

Another advantage of using ehcache for tokens is out of the box clustering support. Tokens can be synchronized (or deprovisioned in case of logout) between cluster nodes.

There a few [ehcache hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214105/hello-world-example-for-ehcache) examples in SO. Your can extend them with [dynamic configuration](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set/co-cfgbasics_dynamically_changing_cache_config.html) to archive what you need.